# Qt .pro file: how to check if I'm compiling with MSVC 2013 toolset?

Tags: qt, qmake

I've tried this condition, but it doesn't work. How to check for MSVC 2013?

```
win32-msvc2013*{
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /FS
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.3 Beta which has `msvc-2013` mkspec.

Comment: What is the Qt version you use?

Comment: @vahancho: Both Qt 4 and Qt 5, but if the solution only works with Qt 5 - that's fine.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1741993/1387438

Comment: @MarekR: that's pretty much what I've tried, isn't it?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, yes, because in Qt 4.x `win32-msvc2013` is not defined in `mkspecs` directory. Maybe you can copy it from your Qt5 installation?

Comment: @vahancho: I'm using Qt 5 built with 2013 atm. If Qt4 doesn't support 2013 out of the box, then I don't care about it.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, maybe I am wrong, but could you check whether this works: `win32-msvc2013 {`? Note the space between `3` and `{`.

Comment: `win32-msvc2013 {` is the correct one.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe note that question it self from link I've given you shows alternative solution.

Comment: @vahancho: nope, no difference, doesn't work. I always write conditions without a space and never had a single problem.

Comment: @MarekR: it shows how to check variables, but I don't know which variable contains "2013".

Comment: First you should write what exactly you want distinguish: msvc vs gcc OR msvs2012 vs msvs2013?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sorry for necroposting, but there seems no googleable solution. Seems I found one. There is vcvars.bat file, which is used for setting correct environment variables for VC. QtCreator, for example, use it while setting Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Compilers. Also it is used for MSVC Command Promt. Let`s check "VisualStudioVersion" env var in qmake (14.0 for MSVS 2015 in my case):

```
win32-msvc* {
    MSVC_VER = $$(VisualStudioVersion)
    equals(MSVC_VER, 14.0){
        message("msvc 2015")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this way:

```
win32-msvc* {
    system(cl|grep "Compiler Version 18.") {
        message( "msvc 2013 detected" )
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /FS
    }
}
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html

Can't test it I don't have Windows machine now.

Comment: Hm. Somehow the message is printed, but `/FS` is not added. How's that possible?.. If I write `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /FS` unconditionally, it is added.

Comment: And sometimes when I run `qmake` I get "grep is not recognized as an external or internal command". Which is probably because Windows doesn't have `grep`. But sometimes it works. Very weird.

Comment: you can try modify this solution by trying find another way to detect contents of standard output of `cl`. `grep` is natural way and it is present in widows for a long time, so ti is very strange that it doesn't works sometimes.

Comment: There is no grep on windows, so this is not a good way to do this. Using $$(VisualStudioVersion) is a better solution.

Comment: `find` is Winodws equivalent of `grep`. Anyway `$$(VisualStudioVersion)` is something new.

Answer (score 5):

I use following:

```
contains(QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES, _MSC_VER=1800) { 
# MSVS2013
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [supported platforms](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/supported-platforms.html#reference-configurations) and table of Reference Configurations. There is no msvc2013!
Newest visual studio supported is 2012.

So when detecting visual studio do not enforce `2013` sufix. 
Just use approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911805/1387438)

Comment: What approach? I need to add a certain flag for MSVC 2013, but not 2012 or 2010. This is not an answer.

Comment: Qt 5.3 Beta, which I'm suing, supports msvc-2013.

Comment: So correct your question. Instead downvoting me, write explicitly what you want distinguish and what version of Qt do you use. Link proves that msvs2013 is NOT SUPPORTED YET BY Qt.

Comment: How is my question not correct? It asks how to check for MSVC **2013**. Not just any MSVC.

Comment: 5.3 Beta comes with `win32-msvc2013` mkspec.

Comment: so write this in question. Note that in comments you have wrote about qt5 and qt4.

Answer (score 0):

found simple and elegant solution:

```
win32-msvc*: {
    COMPIL = $$find(CONFIG, "^win32-msvc*")
    COMPIL = $$replace(COMPIL,win32-,) # 'win32-msvc2017' -> 'msvc2017'
}
```

Edit: this only works with **Qt 5.9.0** and later. Only then configs `win32-msvc2012`/`win32-msvc2013`/etc. are merged into single `win32-msvc`