# How to know in a Qt .pro file if visual studio is the compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, qmake

Is there a way to know if Visual Studio is the compiler in a `.pro` file?

For example there are a lot of ways to detect things in the project file including OS or configuration:

```
CONFIG(boost_asio) {
    DEFINES += BOOST_SOCKETS
    SOURCES += asiosocket.cpp
    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
        -lboost_system
}

OTHER_FILES += 

contains(QT_VERSION, ^5\\.[0-9]\\..*) {
  SOURCES += wavreader.cpp
  HEADERS += wavreader.h
  QT += multimedia
}

include(../../Shared/Common.pri)

windows: { LIBS += -L$$bin -lzip-2 }
!windows: { LIBS += -lzip }
```

What I want is to provide a proper linking to boost libraries on both mingw and boost. But they have names like `boost_chrono-vc120-mt-1_58` which are dependent on the compiler.

Is there any way I can have something like:

```
visualstudio {
   LIBS += -LC:/boost/libs -lboost_system-vc120-mt-1_58
}
```

One way would be to have the user tell which compiler he's using in the `CONFIG` argument of qmake, but I don't think that's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than Visual Studio, you want to check if MSVC is being used.  See here:

[Qt .pro file: how to check if I'm compiling with MSVC 2013 toolset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381727/qt-pro-file-how-to-check-if-im-compiling-with-msvc-2013-toolset)

[qmake: Test for current spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741993/qmake-test-for-current-spec)